# brew services start postgresql not working

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I have installed postgres in Mac using command

`brew install postgresql@9.6` 
and is successfully installed

`brew services start postgresql@9.6` is successful also
`==> Successfully started postgresql@9.6 (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@9.6)`

But when I tried to access Postgres from my Mac terminal `psql postgresql@9.6` it prompt me weird error

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/psql: No such file or directory
```

Am I doing something wrong, how to open psql from my terminal 
Why there is no psql file  in my `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is incorrect.

If you install postgresql@9.6 via Homebrew, the right path for the /bin folder is:
`/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.15/bin`

To connect, just type: `psql postgres`

If you're curious about the connections details, just type `\conninfo` and check it.

Answer (score 0):

You must to enabling Postgres command line tools.

If you are using the default terminal, you are going to want to modify the file at

`~/.bash_profile`

. If you are using something like Oh My Zsh you are going to want to modify the file `~/.zshrc`.

To edit this file you likely need to open it via the terminal, so open your terminal and type open `~/.bash_profile`. You can replace the word open with subl or whatever text editor you prefer.

Once your `zbash_profile` or `.zshrc` file is open, add the following line to the end of the file:

`export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin`

After that you will need to quit and restart your terminal This is to make sure it reloads with the changes you just made.

Once you have restarted your terminal, try running psql.

`psql -U postgres`

You should get the following output.

`psql (9.6.0)`

`Type "help" for help.`

`postgres=#`

You can read more on https://www.calhoun.io/how-to-install-postgresql-9-6-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: but I didn't install Postgres.app application in Applications, then how can I put export PATH and I installed Postgres through homebrew

Comment: how to know which port my Postgres is running on, how can I assume its 5432

Comment: use `pg_lscluster` command or find line port in config file postgresql.conf